# Accessing a specific pod in a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: networking, kubernetes

In my current setup I have an application A, exposed via. NodePort, that the end-user connects to. When that happens, application A then issues a kubectl command to create a static instance of another application B. When application B starts it registers itself with application A, and then runs a setup process from values given to A by the end user.

I do this, since i need to run a stateful application that users can connect to, without being loadbalanced in any way. However, I cannot figure out how to expose this Pod externally.

I tried setting:
`hostNetwork: true` and then start a TcpListener on a specific port, that I then give to Application A, that in return gives this to the end user. However, this doesn't seem to expose my pod, so I might have misunderstood how it works.

tl;dr: 
Is there any approach to exposing a dynamically created static pod externally in Kubernetes?

I'm running my cluster with Microk8s on Ubuntu, if that has anything to say.

Comment: Heads up that "static pod" has a very specific meaning and I don't think you are talking about that.

Comment: @coderanger What i mean is that the pod is created without a service and deployment. Therefore the pod isn't directly managed by the cluster. Does this clarify?

Comment: I have no intention of managing the pod, all I need is a way to connect to it externally somehow. If that's not possible, maybe there is another way of accessing a specific pod? I know of headless services, but those seem to only work internally as they use ClusterIP

Comment: No, a static pod is this https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/static-pod/, created via magic as a bootstrapping mechanism for the control plane. What you are talking about is usually called a "bare pod" or "naked pod". And also you should never do that :)

Comment: Allright point taken, I'm new to Kubernetes so must've misunderstood. Hoewever, what I'm trying to do should be possible somehow. I'm following an existing example from here:
 https://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/MarkMandel/20170502/297222/Scaling_Dedicated_Game_Servers_with_Kubernetes_Part_1__Containerising_and_Deploying.php

Where a pod is started without a deployment or service, and is accessible externally. Any idea how I might achieve this?

Comment: coderanger is right, and he is right, but `hostNetwork: true` should work. What happens?

Comment: @suren When my application B runs it starts a TcpListener on a port from a given range. However, the pod doesn't receive connections on that listener at all.

The application does connect to another application on startup for some configuration, and if I log that connection from the other applications perspective, the remote endpoint is something like 10.0.1.80 and then some random port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my port-forward had broken due to some settings on my router being reset, and therefore I couldn't access my pod externally. Now everything works exactly as I want it to.